# MVC Model Binding before KnockoutJS Model Binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js

So if your Controller Action returns a Model with pre-populated values, how do you make KnockoutJS aware of them?

E.g.:

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { data_bind="value: title"} )`

however, on `$(document).ready()` where I bind knockout.js ViewModel, this value isn't yet populated:

```
$(document).ready({
  var viewModel = {
    title: ko.observable($("#Title").val()) // too early for this?!
  }

  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);​
});
```

How do you make KnockoutJS work with MVC's model binding?
One workaround I found was to set the JavaScript variable in my Razor View, like so:

```
<script>
  var strTitle = '@Model.Title';
</script>
```

and than use it in the Knockout model binding. That works, but I hate it. What if your form has like hundreds of fields? You don't want as many JavaScript variables in your page.
Am I missing the obvious here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10886795/knockout-js-load-form-into-viewmodel/10887875#10887875).  Normally you would set your view model by converting @Model to JSON in a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var model = @(new HtmlString(new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model)));
</script>
```

You could also create your own binding handler that will initially load the view model based on control values.  This new `myvalue` handler basically calls the existing `value` handler, except it updates the view model *from* the initial control value on init.

```
ko.bindingHandlers['myvalue'] = {
    'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        // call existing value init code
        ko.bindingHandlers['value'].init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);

        // valueUpdateHandler() code
        var modelValue = valueAccessor();
        var elementValue = ko.selectExtensions.readValue(element);
        modelValue(elementValue); // simplified next line, writeValueToProperty isn't exported
        //ko.jsonExpressionRewriting.writeValueToProperty(modelValue, allBindingsAccessor, 'value', elementValue, /* checkIfDifferent: */ true);
    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // call existing value update code
        ko.bindingHandlers['value'].update(element, valueAccessor);
    }
};
```

Then when you call ko.applyBindings, your observable will be set based on the control's value initially:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="myvalue: Title" value="This Title will be used" />
<input type="text" data-bind="value: Title" value="This will not be used" />
<!-- MVC -->
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { data_bind="myvalue: Title"} )
```

[SAMPLE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YG8Tu/3/)

Comment: thanks, unfortunately this doesn't seem to work for me :( the value disappears after `ko` model binding because of this line: `"viewModel.Title = ko.observable()"`

Comment: ...and if I do viewModel.Title = ko.observable(viewModel.Title) to set initial value, knockout.validation.js throws "Uncaught TypeError"

Comment: @Tsar - I updated the answer to get it to work and gave an example fiddle, the ko.jsonExpressionRewriting.writeValueToProperty function is not exported and only worked with the debug version of knockout, I changed it to a simpler call that should work as long as Title is an observable.

Answer (score 2):

What about simply serializing your entire page model to json using JSON.NET or similar. Then your page will be populated via normal razor view bindings for non-js users. Then your page scripts can be something like:

```
<script>
    ko.applyBindings(@Html.ToJSON(Model));
</script>
```

Or if you have a typed viewModel

```
<script>
    var viewModel = new MyViewModel(@Html.ToJSON(Model));
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>
```

It makes sense to structure your client side and actual view models the same so no manipulation of the json shape is required.

**EDIT**

Example of the toJSON helper.

```
public static MvcHtmlString ToJson(this HtmlHelper html, object obj)
{
  JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
  return MvcHtmlString.Create(serializer.Serialize(obj));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: where did toJSON() come from? Do I need to write this method in my MVC Model?

Comment: Yeh sorry should really have explained that. Wrote this on a phone :) Edited to give example.

Comment: @JasonGoemaat - No I don't good spot. Should learn to never answer questions until I can run the code. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

Because I don't have a 50 point reputation to add a comment to the [Jason Goemaat answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10643940/knockout-js-access-viewmodel-in-javascript-function-outside-viewmodels-scope/10644169#10644169), I decided to add my comment here as an answer.

All the credits go to Jason Goemaat.

I wasn't able to make the code work for me. So I had to make a small change.

```
        ko.bindingHandlers['myvalue'] = {
    'init': function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        //get initial state of the element            
        var modelValue = valueAccessor();
        var elementValue = ko.selectExtensions.readValue(element);

        // call existing value init code
        ko.bindingHandlers['value'].init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);

        //Save initial state
        modelValue(elementValue);
    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        // call existing value update code
        ko.bindingHandlers['value'].update(element, valueAccessor);
    }
};
```

if I had this line at the top,

```
// call existing value init code
ko.bindingHandlers['value'].init(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor);
```

It was deleting the original state of the element. So whatever value I had in the input field, it was being deleted.

Inside the model I have this:

```
//publishing comment
self.publishingComment = ko.observable();
```

And my MVC looks like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Comment, new { data_bind = "myvalue: publishingComment" })
```